# Как решить эти ошибки? Уже и так и сяк удалял, а ошибки остаются!

Tags: c#, unity3d

```
public void ReportHighScore(int bestScore) { 
Social.localUser.Authenticate((bool success) => { 
 if (success) { 
  Social.ReportScore(bestScore, 
   "CnyIgyminBaUteKR", 
   (bool success2) => { 
    //Handle Report Success 
   }); 
  }); //error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `)'
 } 
} //error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `}'
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не жалейте отступов и пустых строк.

```
public void ReportHighScore(int bestScore) { 

    Social.localUser.Authenticate((bool success) => { 

        if (success) { 

            Social.ReportScore(bestScore, "CnyIgyminBaUteKR", (bool success2) => { 
                //Handle Report Success 
            }); 
            //}); !!!

        } 

    }); // !!!

}
```

Comment: Спасибо, ошибка исчезла!